# SVG and text masking animation

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

i've created a 'marquee' animation with static background and text masking on the background. I'm using svg text to mask to the background and only apply @keyframes animation to the text.

Here's the demo https://codepen.io/syedzaquan/pen/VwEjaYE

```css
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.marquee text {
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 8rem;
  text-anchor: middle;
  animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.marquee image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
}

.marquee #image-hello {
  mask: url(#text-mask-hello);
}
```

```html
<section class="marquee section">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <defs>
                <mask id="text-mask-hello" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
                    <text id="text" x="100%" y="50%">Humble Beginnings Humble Beginnings Humble Beginnings Humble Beginnings Humble Beginnings Humble Beginnings Humble Beginnings Humble Beginnings Humble Beginnings</text>
                </mask>
            </defs>
            <image id="image-hello" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502691876148-a84978e59af8?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
        </svg>
</section>
```

My question is why the animation didn't work in Safari MacOS and IOS?

And a weird issue, it's working fine in stackoverflow code snippet demo but not in the Codepen demo. Any ideas?

Comment: A weird issue: in both StackOverflow code snipper and in Codepen, I need to keep moving the mouse (and the cursor must be within the frame), otherwise the animation stops.

Comment: @qrsngky interestingly, that is not the case for me, the animation is running infinitely after I click "Run code snippet" without any further interaction from me (same for codepen) using google chrome (in case that matters, though ig they run in their own sandbox)

Comment: @MissSkooter yeah the issue is not the same between desktop, mobile and sandbox (Codepen and code snippet also different). This is my first time seeing this kind of issue

Comment: @qrsngky but for me it only happened in Codepen and it's working fine in Code snippet